# Is blog.stackoverflow.com really missing?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

The [link to the 2016 developer survey blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/you-can-now-download-stack-overflows-2016-developer-survey-data/?cb=1) leads to an error page.

[image]

> ## Couldn't find blog.stackoverflow.com
>
> The Q&A site **blog.stackoverflow.com** doesn't seem to exist... yet.

[image]

Comment: Strange, can't reproduce this. Still happening?

Comment: Hmmm... it works now. That's so strange... maybe that particular resource wasn't actually available when I first clicked? I wonder when that post went live. Regardless, that particular error served from stackexchange is weird as all hell.

Comment: That you saw a SE 404 page when you tried that route pretty well hints at the request happening at _precisely_ the most inopportune time :) Think it was just one of those flukes.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks. Glad it's not a persistent issue. ;)